# How do you drop a shadow of an objects/path in SVG using Raphael?

Tags: javascript, raphael

How do you drop a shadow of an objects/path in SVG using Raphael? I was able to create a rounded rectangle and now I am trying to drop the shadow.I hear there is a plugin and said it was available here https://github.com/DmitryBaranovskiy/raphael/blob/master/plugins/raphael.blur.js,but was displayed with page not found.Could some one please help? I know the question has been asked heree before and I got the above link from one of the answers but the link doesnt work.

Answer (score 0):

You could try [this](https://raw.github.com/dahoo/raphael.dropshadow.js/master/raphael.dropshadow.js) one. Doesn't support VML (IE) yet, but it is a start...